# How to check whether the group of time are sequence or not in R

Tags: r, time, sequence

If I have this data

```
Group,start_time
1,9:05:00
1,9:07:00
1,19:09:00
1,9:00:00
1,9:00:00
1,9:02:00
2,9:05:00
2,9:07:00
2,19:09:00
2,9:00:00
2,9:00:00
2,9:02:00
```

and I would like to get a column check on my data like below. How can I do that? Thanks

```
Group,start_time, check
1,9:05:00,True
1,9:07:00,True
1,19:09:00, True
1,9:00:00,False
1,9:00:00,False
1,9:02:00,False
2,9:05:00,True
2,9:07:00,True
2,19:09:00,True
2,9:00:00,False
2,9:00:00,False
2,9:02:00,False
```

Comment: What is the philosophy behind the checking? Why True or False?

Comment: it can be anything actually, for example 0 for False or 1 for True.

Comment: :) yes... but why?

Comment: I would like to change with sequence time after I know which groups are wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
df = structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), start_time = structure(c(4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("19:09:00", "9:00:00", "9:02:00", 
"9:05:00", "9:07:00"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(check = as.numeric(gsub(":","",start_time)) >= cummax(as.numeric(gsub(":","",start_time)))) %>%
  ungroup() 

# # A tibble: 12 x 3
#   Group start_time check
#   <int> <fct>      <lgl>
# 1     1 9:05:00    TRUE 
# 2     1 9:07:00    TRUE 
# 3     1 19:09:00   TRUE 
# 4     1 9:00:00    FALSE
# 5     1 9:00:00    FALSE
# 6     1 9:02:00    FALSE
# 7     2 9:05:00    TRUE 
# 8     2 9:07:00    TRUE 
# 9     2 19:09:00   TRUE 
#10     2 9:00:00    FALSE
#11     2 9:00:00    FALSE
#12     2 9:02:00    FALSE
```

I'm assuming that `FALSE` cases are the ones that we seem to go back in time.

In order to compare times I remove `:` and I create a number using the remaining (numerical) characters.